# Is it possible to make an Android/iPhone app which will show info on a locked screen?

Tags: android, ios

I want to make an app (for both Android and iPhone) where user puts some info to the app and that info (text) will be then permanently shown on a lock screen. Is it possible to make something like this? If yes, how please?

Comment: Not on Android. On Android 5.0+, you can have a `Notification` show up on the lockscreen, but that `Notification` will also be in the user's status bar and such.

Comment: Not on iOS neither. You can show a local notification, but that is not permanent.

Comment: Hi, you won't be able to show info on lock screen. But you can create an extension that's viewable from lock screen. Check my answer for more info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't show any info permanently on lock screen on iOS. There is no `App Extension` for that. But, something close to that can be done by creating `Today Widget` in iOS. The widget can be viewable even when device is locked. You just need to swipe down. For more info on creating it. Please look into the following tutorial:

https://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today/

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can only add notifications. What you are referring to would involve jailbreaking.